# Calling location from viewDidAppear method of viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, locationmanager

My application gets the user's location in the appDelegate and calls that location in the viewDidAppear method of some viewControllers. My problem is that the first time the viewController's load, there hasn't been enough time to get the user's location.

**Here is my AppDelegate:**

```
- (NSString *)getUserCoordinates
{
NSString *userCoordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", 
locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
return userCoordinates;
}

- (NSString *)getUserLatitude
{
NSString *userLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
return userLatitude;
}

- (NSString *)getUserLongitude
{
NSString *userLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 
locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
return userLongitude;
}
```

**Here is what I am using to call the location from the viewControllers:**

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSString *userLatitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
getUserLatitude];

NSString *userLongitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
getUserLongitude];
}
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use global variables here. It will be updated as your location updates and you will have updated location cordinates all time.

```
-(void)didUpdateLocation // location update method of CLLocation Manager class
{
// assign current ordinates values to global variables.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you posted the same question two times... but see my answer at your other post,

[Pass Coordinates from locationManager in appDelegate to viewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14179651/pass-coordinates-from-locationmanager-in-appdelegate-to-viewcontroller)

In short, you need to implement the delegate methods of CoreLocation, as those methods are called when a new location is found. In those delegate methods, fire off an NSNotification (which ViewControllers) subscribe to in order to get the new user's location.